# Finding any class or id location

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I have a wordpress website using XSTORE Theme I want to display price in shop page it is not displaying on shop pge but on home page or any other page price is being displayed. I inspected the element no price div is created in woocommerce archieve pages like shop or cateogory. I found a plugin name LOCO TRANSLATE but it only tells the location of a text. I want to find a location of class or id. Please help me so that i can go to particular file nd copy paste code that is being used on other pages to show  price.

I tried different plugins but failed to find location. Expecting to get  plugin or any method to find location of class or ID.

**woocommerce-Price-amount** this is the class on other pages but on shop page the whole div is not created for displying price.

Comment: Just do a simple file search for this class on your OS or IDE for the class and copy the code.